# Steps to debug KnockoutJs observable array matching

Tags: knockout.js

I'm totally stuck.

Given a static observable array:

```
obj.allRoles = ko.observableArray([
    new Role(1, "Adminx"),
    new Role(2, "Temp2x"),
    new Role(3, "Temp3x")
    ]);
```

bound to a select

```
<select data-bind="options: allRoles, 
                optionsText: 'RoleName',
                optionsValue: 'RoleId',                    
                optionsCaption: 'Add a new role...', 
                value: selectedRole">
</select>
```

and a function that runs via a click binding:

```
function addRole() {

        alert('got id:' + obj.selectedRole());

        var selectedId = obj.selectedRole();
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(obj.allRoles(), function (item) {
            return item.RoleId == selectedId;
        });

        alert('got :' + match.RoleName);
        return;
}
```

All is well. The first alert shows obj.SelectedRole() returns the value of a select option
and the second alert shows a match is found and the RoleName is displayed. OK so far.

If I replace the static observable array for one populated from a service, eg:

```
obj.allRoles = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and

```
//data
    function loadAllRolesFromSvc() {
        var url = '/api/UserSvc/GetAllRoles';
        $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {
                obj.allRoles.removeAll();

                var results = ko.observableArray();
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);

                for (var i = 0; i < results().length; i++) {                        
                    var role = new Role();
                    role.RoleId = results()[i].RoleId;
                    role.RoleName = results()[i].RoleName;
                    obj.allRoles.push(role);                        
                };
            }
        );
    };
```

Then I see the select populated OK, but when the addRole() function is run the first alert shows that selectedRole is provided with a value, but the code to locate the matching Role object by RoleId (in addRole()) fails - the match is always null.

How can I fix this?
All pointers welcome.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `RoleId` and `RoleName` properties in `Role` class are not observable, but in `loadAllRolesFromSvc` function you set them to be observable.

The code `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);` convers all properties inside results to observableArrays and observables. Really, I don't understand why are you convert results to observable. So to fix issue you could remove mapping:

```
   function loadAllRolesFromSvc() {
        var url = '/api/UserSvc/GetAllRoles';
        $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {
                obj.allRoles.removeAll();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                        
                    var role = new Role();
                    role.RoleId = data[i].RoleId;
                    role.RoleName = data[i].RoleName;
                    obj.allRoles.push(role);                        
                };
            }
        );
    };
```

Or you could unwrap `RoleId` and `RoleName` values:

```
function loadAllRolesFromSvc() {
    var url = '/api/UserSvc/GetAllRoles';
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {
            obj.allRoles.removeAll();

            var results = ko.observableArray();
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);

            for (var i = 0; i < results().length; i++) {                        
                var role = new Role();
                role.RoleId = results()[i].RoleId();
                role.RoleName = results()[i].RoleName();
                obj.allRoles.push(role);                        
            };
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: I see (kind of) - I confused myself with the mapping plugin. I'll re-read the documentation ;) Thanks to you it's working now. I really appreciate your help on this. Big Love & Merry Christmas.